# How to pick up a single character from a string using Java?

Tags: java

For example, `"this is yahoo answers"`, from here I want to pick up each single character and convert it into its ASCII value. How can I do it?

Comment: Also: please forget about ASCII values, they are pretty much irrelevant now. It's all about the Unicode codepoint (a.k.a "Unicode value").

Comment: Do realize that not all characters are known in the ASCII system, or require a code table to decode the extended characters like ë, or î. Which means that the code itself isn't sufficient. If you're dealing with plain english however you might get away with ASCII codes :)

Comment: @extraneon: actually the first 128 codepoints of Unicode are exactly equivalent to the 128 possible values of ASCII, so you don't need any code tables.

Comment: @Joachim, well yes, the plain english characters plus some basic controls are ASCII. But nowadays it's best to take into consideration that people expect software to work even if some strange characters crop up in the code. Like this comment which now has an ü.

Comment: @extraneon: I'm pretty aware of that (see my first comment). I was just commenting on the part "or require a code table to decode": All characters that ASCII *can* actually represent use the same number for their Unicode codepoint as for the ASCII value.

Answer (score 5):

Your question is a bit vague, but probably you meant to want this?

```
for (char c : "this is yahoo answers".toCharArray()) {
    System.out.println((int) c);
}
```

This produces the following:

```
116
104
105
115
32
105
115
32
121
97
104
111
111
32
97
110
115
119
101
114
115
```

Casting the `char` to an `int` will display its [*codepoint*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point).

Answer (score 3):

```
   String s = "stackoverflow.com"; 

    for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++) {
     int ascii = (int) s.charAt(i) ;
     // .....
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for(int i = 0; i< theString.length; i++)
  theString.charAt(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to support the whole unicode range, including for example the emoticons new in 6.0 (http://unicode.org/Public/6.0.0/charts/versioned/U1F600.pdf), you could try this:

```
for (int i=0, len=string.length(); i<len; ++i) {
    int codepoint = Character.codePointAt(string, i);
    if (codepoint > Character.MAX_VALUE) {
        ++i;
    }
    System.out.println(codepoint);
}
```

Otherwise, if you are sure that the input will only be ascii, why not state this assumption in the code like this:

```
byte[] ascii = string.getBytes("US-ASCII");
for (int i=0, len=ascii.length; i<len; ++i) {
    int ch = ascii[i];
    System.out.println(ch);
}
```

This should throw a nice exception if the code happens to contain non-ascii characters.

Comment: I like the way you make the assumption - US-ASCII - explicit in the code.